# SQL Cross referencing matrix

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Don't think I found a solution for this particular one around - if there is, I'm sorry for bad search skills!

I have a single table with student registrations and I have been asked to produce a report with a double entry matrix with pairs of curricular units that share student registrations, as such (my description is messy so I'll ilustrate):

Original table:

[image]

Intended result:

[image]

Is this possible/feasible?

The original table is a simple 2 column table with student - unit - http://pastebin.com/RfHYHK91

Comment: Questions asking for code must show a minimal effort. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008R2.
I admit I don't yet have a semi-functioning aproach to this. I'm reading into the pivot option, but the only thing coming to mind is using a cursor to test each unit individually against each other. I'll post if I get something similar to working...

Comment: It looks like a good case for `PIVOT` -- so if you're just asking if it's /possible/...  :-)  Yes, I'd expect so.

Comment: Can you explain your logic?  Why does `Col A` with `Row B` have a result of 2?

Comment: Col A with row B has a result of 2 because there are two students enrolled in both units. Row D has zeros because there are no students enrolled in both unit D and any other.

Comment: OK -- so if A has 2 B's, then why doesn't B have 2 A's?

Comment: It does - I just filled in half of the matrix since the other half would be equal - probably should have clarified that - Using your answer to look into pivoting, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

This is what a PIVOT might look like using a COUNT() of the student ID...  But I can't quite figure out how you're calculating your values -- for example, A/C cross should be 2(?) not 1, etc.  Anyway...:

```
DECLARE @student TABLE (unit VARCHAR(1), student INT)
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'A',1
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'A',2
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'A',3
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'B',1
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'B',2
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'C',1
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'C',3
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'D',4

SELECT unit, [A] AS A,[B] AS B, [C] AS C,[D] AS D
FROM
(SELECT unit, unit AS u, student FROM @student) AS S
PIVOT
(
COUNT(student)
FOR u IN([A],[B],[C],[D])
) AS P;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an output that looks (almost) exactly like your desired output (not a very usable approach though, if you needed to add/remove units, as that would be a manual effort each time):

```
DECLARE @student TABLE (unit VARCHAR(1), student INT)
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'A',1
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'A',2
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'A',3
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'B',1
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'B',2
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'C',1
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'C',3
INSERT INTO @student SELECT 'D',4

SELECT 'A','-' AS A, '' AS B, '' AS C, '' AS D
UNION
SELECT 'B',CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(a.student)) AS A, '-' AS B, '' AS C, '' AS D FROM @student A INNER JOIN @student B ON A.student = B.student AND A.unit = 'A' AND B.unit = 'B'
UNION
SELECT 'C',CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(a.student)), CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(b.student)), '-','' FROM @student A INNER JOIN @student C ON A.student = C.student AND A.unit = 'A' AND C.unit = 'C' LEFT JOIN @student B ON B.student = C.student AND B.unit = 'B' AND C.unit = 'C'
UNION
SELECT 'D',CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(a.student)), CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(b.student)), CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(c.student)),'-' FROM @student A INNER JOIN @student D ON A.student = D.student AND A.unit = 'A' AND D.unit = 'D' LEFT JOIN @student B ON B.student = D.student AND B.unit = 'B' AND D.unit = 'D' LEFT JOIN @student C ON D.student = C.student AND C.unit = 'C' AND D.unit = 'D'
```

Comment: Works as intended, but unfortunately not very useful - I have 37 units with 1100 rows :/